# Object animation removes drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I do a color animaiton of a LinearLayout using

```
    main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_screen_background);
    ArgbEvaluator e = new ArgbEvaluator();
    flashBackgroundRed = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(main, "backgroundColor", e, Color.RED, getResources().getColor(R.color.background_orange));
    flashBackgroundGreen.setDuration(500);
    flashBackgroundRed.start();
```

The original background of that `LinearLayout` is a drawable defining the colors and a set of rounded corners. It seems the animation removes the drawable and the corners are gone after the first flash.

After API 16 I could use `main.setBackground(drawable_with_rounded_corners);` but I'm aiming for API 14 and above.

Is there any good way to solve this programmatically?

Comment: As far as I know, any call to setBackgroundColor, setBackgroundDrawable and setDrawableResource will replace the BACKGROUND, I can't see your code working the way you want with this.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos If it can't work the way I have done it, how would you do it then?

Comment: Using an animation that does change the alpha between two images probably

Comment: I actually use a AnimationListener to restore it after the animation is done. Has some ugly spots but its good enough. Will post that as än answer låter.